# removing folder via regex in htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess

While I'm good with many things scripting and programming, the one thing I never really got into is regex.

I'm tweaking a third party script that uses the url structure of site.com/username/p/seo-friendly-link. I want it to be site.com/username/seo-friendly-link instead

its .htaccess file has

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/p/(.*)$ ./dir/pages/post.php?user=$1&pid=$2
RewriteRule ^p/(.*)$ ./dir/pages/post.php?pid=$1
```

when I remove /p as

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/(.*)$ ./dir/pages/post.php?user=$1&pid=$2
```

I see it the error in the apache logs as

```
[error] [client ::1] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

I've tried adding the L to the end of the unmodified rule and it still gives the same error.

I want to learn regex, but I feel like this particular example isn't that noob friendly and it'd instead led to more confusion.

can someone explain what those two lines do, how to get what I need or why it's not as simple as it seems?

Comment: Is 3rd party script creating href links as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an expert in .htaccess configuration rules, but as far the regex is concerned the problem seems to be that `^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/(.*)$` covers too many possible matches because of the last `(.*)` group which literally matches anything.

In other words, `^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/(.*)$` matches both `username/p/seo-friendly-link` and `username/seo-friendly-link`. It will *also* match the target part `dir/pages/post.php?user=$1&pid=$2`, probably leading to the infinite redirects.

To restrict the regex, you should exclude the `/` from the second group. So instead of `(.*)`, use `[^/]*` where `[^/]` defines a [*character class*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) that matches any character except `/`:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([^/]*)$ ./dir/pages/post.php?user=$1&pid=$2
```

Comment: great explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Change the first line to

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/p/(.*)$ ./dir/pages/post.php?user=$1&pid=$2 [L,NC,R]
```

This makes the url redirect and asserts it is the last rule to be checked.

Comment: it just redirects to /dir/pages/post.php?user=username&pid=some-seo-link in the browser